# Check values inside a LINQ Sum() method with lambdas in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have to **sum** all the values in one object. The values are retrieved from a database and stored in a `List<T>`. If one of the value is equal to -1 I want to use 0 in the sum instead.

Here is the code that I use to perform the task:

```
lprod_projectionActualvalue = lprod_monthlyReport.Sum(m => new
{
    Monthly_ActualValue = (m.Monthly_ActualValue != -1) ? 
      m.Monthly_ActualValue : 0F
});
```

**Monthly_ActualValue** is of type **float?**. The compiler gives me an error stating that I **cannot convert anonymous type to float?**. That is quite strange because I use the same code in the Select clause without getting any error. 
What could be the problem?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating a new anonymous type using the `new {}` keyword and brackets, which is never going to be convertible to a float. If you want the sum to be of a float, remove the anonymous type declaration and just specify the expression producing the float, like so:

```
lprod_projectionActualvalue = lprod_monthlyReport.Sum(m => (m.Monthly_ActualValue != -1) ? m.Monthly_ActualValue : 0F);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're creating an anonymous type using `new { ... }` for no particularly obvious reason... and `Sum` doesn't know how to add up values of the anonymous type Try this instead:

```
lprod_projectionActualvalue = lprod_monthlyReport
    .Sum(m => m.Monthly_ActualValue != -1 ? m.Monthly_ActualValue : 0F);
```

I'm slightly surprised by using a nullable type *and* a magic "doesn't count" value (-1). Normally you only need one of those options - but I'll take your word for it that this is really what you want :)

(I would suggest you look at the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) too... those underscores aren't conventional, and it's unclear to me what `lprod` means. Just general advice.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using this instruction because when there is an empty value I use -1 throughout the application, but when I have to sum I have to consider this empty value as 0. I am aware of the naming conventions but that class is generated by the EF from database and that one is the naming convention used in the DB. I know I can change from the EF but I prefer to leave like this to make the variables more "traceable"

Comment: @Francesco: Why are you using -1 instead of using a `Nullable<T>` null value? That's the whole point of `Nullable<T>` - to get away from magic numbers.

Comment: I take the data from a database that it was not designed by me and I cannot use null. Moreover if I need to use a counter variable I cannot use the type var and inizialize it to null.

Comment: @Francesco: There *is* no type `var`. Don't use `var` as a crutch to avoid using the right types. But you've said that the type of `Monthly_ActualValue` is already `float?` - why not convert -1 to a null value when you read the data? It's pointless having a nullable type with an *extra* value to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding a select first, then call the Sum method

```
lprod_projectionActualvalue = lprod_monthlyReport.Select(m => new
{
    Monthly_ActualValue = (m.Monthly_ActualValue != -1) ? m.Monthly_ActualValue : 0F
}).Sum(m => m.Monthly_ActualValue);
```

Comment: This works, but the select isn't even necessary; it'll perform a little better by just summing the expression being assigned to Monthly_ActualValue.

Comment: @KeithS - Good point, but I like the simplicity of the Sum method

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda does not return a `float`. It declares a new anonymous type with a single `float` property, `Monthly_ActualValue`. You cannot `Sum` objects of this type because addition is not defined for it.

Try this instead:

```
lprod_projectionActualvalue = lprod_monthlyReport.Sum(m =>
    (m.Monthly_ActualValue != -1) ? m.Monthly_ActualValue : 0F
);
```